# Should I be sending my SharePoint <Batch> xml to create multiple folders in my list in one request?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I wrote a class called `BatchSharePointUpdater` to create a single `<Batch>` xml node and add to it a bunch of XML `<Method>` commands queued up to be sent to the SharePoint server.  Once I have all of the commands queued up in my `BatchSharePointUpdater` instance I run it's `commitBatchOperation()` to send the entire `<Batch>` xml node and it's children to the SharePointServer.

The idea was to send one request with everything in it, including operations like list deletion and creation.

At the time I wrote my `BatchSharePointUpdater` I had falsely assumed that operations such as list creation and deletion would be included in the `wsProxy.UpdateListItems(listName, batchRootNode)` method which is called when I run the `BatchSharePointUpdater.commitBatchOperation()`, however it appears that this isn't the case.

This has left me wondering if I should really be keeping all things folder creation to be sent in a single request.  My `BatchSharePointUpdater` doesn't really seem worth all the effort in light of the fact that you can't send list creation and deletion in a single request.

Am I right or wrong in thinking this?